# CSS - line-clamp in Safari and absolutely positioned button misaligned

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I have a component in which I would like to line clamp some text. If it is clamped at two lines I would display a button with "See More" at the bottom right. This displays great for Chrome, MS Edge, and Firefox but in **Safari** the button is not correctly aligned with the other text. I know line-clamp is still a draft spec and not officially supported but I'm not sure why the alignment is so off.

(using tailwindcss for styling)

```html
<div class="relative mb-2">
  <p class="clamped leading-open text-md md:text-lg text-color-text whitespace-pre-wrap line-clamp-5">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>

  <button class="see-more-button bg-white text-md md:text-lg border-0 leading-open p-0 cursor-pointer absolute bottom-0 right-0 hover:underline" type="button">…see more</button>

</div>
```

```css
.clamped {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
}
```

Link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-gould-9m5md1?file=/src/App.js because I cannot paste all the tailwindcss

Screenshot[image: alignment incorrect]

Comment: FYI, there's a line-clamp plugin for Tailwind if you want to keep from adding your own class: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#line-clamp

Comment: Did you add a custom utility class for `leading-open`? That class is not a Tailwind default: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/line-height

Comment: @EdLucas yeah, I'm using the plugin but didn't set it up in the codesandbox. leading-open is just line-height: 1.5

Comment: Added more css classes I thought missing